Linear Regression and ridge regression resulting in similar coefficients
The coefficients I am obtaining from linear regression are similar to the ridge regression. I have tried to understand where I am getting wrong I could not figure out. It would be very helpful if someone can point me where I am wrong.
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

ss = StandardScaler()

X_scl = ss.fit_transform(X)
y_scl = ss.fit_transform(y)

sk_lr = LinearRegression()
sk_lr.fit(X_scl,y_scl)

alpha=0.01
sk_ridge = Ridge(alpha=alpha)
sk_ridge.fit(X_scl,y_scl)

x = np.arange(len(X.columns))

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

plt.bar(x=x-.2,height=sk_lr.coef_[0],width=0.4)
plt.bar(x=x+.2,height=sk_ridge.coef_[0],width=0.4)

plt.xticks(ticks=x,rotation=90,labels = X.columns)

plt.show()

The data I am using kc_house_train_data.csv

Welcome to Cross Validated !! Your coefficients may appear similar because alpha=0.01 is too small, causing Ridge to behave like OLS. Increase alpha (e.g., 1 or 10) to observe a clearer difference. Avoid scaling y (i.e., use y instead of y_scl) since Ridge penalizes coefficients in the scale of y. Compare coefficients numerically using diff = sk_lr.coef_ - sk_ridge.coef_ and plot these differences for clarity. Finally, check collinearity in X using the condition number (np.linalg.cond(X_scl)); if it's low, Ridge may have minimal impact. These steps should clarify the similarity in coefficients

If there’s no multicollinearity and $\alpha$ is small, ridge regression coefficients can very close to those from OLS. Ridge regression adds an $L_2$ penalty to shrink coefficients, but if predictors aren’t correlated and the design matrix is well-conditioned the penalty has minimal effect. Standardising features ensures Ridge applies evenly across predictors, and with small $\alpha$the regularisation term contributes little to the loss. This makes ridge regression act almost like OLS, slightly reducing coefficient magnitudes without altering their relative values much.

Thank you very much @RobertLong.
